# How to turn off the Firefox cache?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

I'm using [Firefox 3.5.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Version_3.5). For some reason, it has cached a page and won't update. For example, I added an `alert('test');` statement to some JavaScript code which is loaded on the page, but Firefox doesn't see it. When I do a view source, I still see the old code.

So I'm guessing this is a cache issue. How can I fix it, or can I make Firefox **never** cache anything from `http://localhost`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can force all requests relating to a refresh to actually be requested from the server (bypassing any already cached content, and updating the cache with the new version) by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> instead of just <kbd>F5</kbd>.

This does not work for requests made by the page within client-side code though. When that is a problem you need to use the `POST` method (`POST` requests should never be cached) instead of `GET` or add an ever-changing value to the query string (such as the current time in ms).

Comment: Also ctrl+shift+R, which doesn't require as large a hand spread if done one-handed.

Comment: Another trick is to add a question mark to the end of the url.

Comment: What is the mac shortcut?

Comment: for mac its Shift+CMD+R

Comment: Using angular to fetch templates with XHR calls you can press the entire keyboard with F5 but it'll still fetch the cached template. Do does any ajax request from script.

Comment: @emgee, That would give you a different page  depending on your server.

Comment: ctrl+shift+R is ok with Ubuntu 16.04, in my installation ctrl+F5 launches a terminal.

Answer (score 89):

Turn off the caching for a particular page.  the correct way is to set the cache directive in  Http request:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

turn the entire Firefox caching capability off through its about:config page

```
network.http.use-cache = false.
```

Comment: Spot on with about:config. When using the HttpFox extension, I’ve found that Cmd+Shift+R (I’m on a Mac) doesn’t always result in everything being fetched from the cache. Turning the cache off in about:config seems to work reliably though.

Comment: Note that this should be the accepted answer, the one that's accepted is useless.

Comment: If you landed here through google and do not have an ancient firefox: http://askubuntu.com/questions/776522/how-to-disable-cache-in-firefox

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch: Not useless, but simply not answering the question.

Comment: It seems to be outdated. With Firefox 63 the key to set to false is `browser.cache.memory.enable`

Answer (score 44):

If you use FireBug, on the Network tab's drop down menu there is an option do disable the browser's cache.

Comment: Built-in developer tools also have this option now.

Comment: The drop-down menu seems to have disappeared entirely.

Answer (score 11):

If you install the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) addon, it gives you an extra toolbar where you can disable the cache among other things. I highly recommend that and [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) if you are working on webpages or scripts.

Answer (score 11):

Firefox addon [CacheViewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2489) allows you to explicitly delete a specific cached page.
 <sub>I find it quite useful when Superuser-Beta updates and my cache causes things to vanish from the edit pages.</sub>

There is one more addon called [**JohnnyCache**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3817) at [this article](http://drupal.org/node/330416).

> In theory, **Johnnycache** can prevent cache access for individual files or paths - which would be perfection. In practice, this doesn't work in some cases (maybe I'm giving it the wrong path somehow).
>
> You can use Johnnycache to block caching for the entire site under development (just use yoursitename.com). This always works, but it can slow down loading of complex pages. But I'd suggest doing this when you first install Johnnycache, to get an idea how it works.

The bad thing is that Johnnycache doesn't work for Firefox 26.0

Comment: Why's it called JohnnyCache?

Comment: @Pacerier - The name is likely in reference to "Johnny Cab" from the 1990 movie "Total Recall".

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the best way I have found is to click on TOOLS in firefox and start private browsing which does not cache any pages and will restore any pages you had open prior to going in to PRIVATE BROWSING. Nice feature.

Answer (score 2):

On android devices, use the following settings in `about:config` to disable the browser cache:

```
browser.cache.disk.enable = False
browser.cache.memory.enable = False
```

Answer (score 1):

On Firefox 4, use [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config). In the filter, type `cache`. Toggle all toggles to false. Be careful, don't change any sizes, just the toggles.

Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> for the refreshes. This also works well for page speed testing.

Comment: is there any way to reliably test that the cache is disabled for good?

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions, you can set up Firefox so the http cache is disabled whenever you have the Inspector open, which is very handy for development. (I'm using Firefox Developer Edition 61)

- Open the Inspector (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> on Mac).
- Open settings by clicking the three dots at the top-right of the Inspector and then selecting "Settings"

[image]

- On the page that opens, make sure the following option is checked under "Advanced settings:" "Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)"

[image]

That's it. Whenever you have the Inspector open, the cache will be automatically disabled.

Answer (score 0):

### 2018 - about:config settings

In 2018 some of the Firefox about:config settings mentioned in earlier answers no longer exist.

In **about:config** settings, to turn off Firefox web cache set-:
**
browser.cache.disk.enable**=**false**

---

### Private Browser

Another way to disable cache is to simply open a Private Browser using the hamburger menu or shortcut **CTRL** + **SHIFT** + **P**