# How can I always force a reload for some url?

Tags: linux, firefox, browser-cache

Is it possible, and if so how do I achieve it, that Firefox automatically force-reloads (no cache) some urls/domains?

For example, say I never want to load google.com from cache. Can I set it so that whenever I either visit this site or do a relaod with F5 cache is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Firefox address bar and type:

> about:config

type this into the filter:

> browser.cache.check_doc_frequency

change the value to:

> 1

If Firefox value be number 3 only check if it seems outdated.

If Firefox value be number 2 always use cached version.

If Firefox value be number 1 always check for newer version.

If Firefox value be number 0 check for newer version once per session.

Comment: More details including caveats to be found [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.check_doc_frequency).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/23134/how-to-turn-off-the-firefox-cache) for a number of solutions.

Although none disable cache for a particular URL, there are options to turn off cache or use private browsing where nothing is cached. If you have a control over the page, then you can turn off caching this page using POST instead of GET, or using `Cache-Control: no-cache` in the webpage.

Comment: So, it's not possible in the way I want it?