# browsing new data; not cached data

Tags: cdn

How do I cause Firefox to display only new data; not cached data. In particular I am concerned about old data in all interstitial locations such as Content Delivery Networks (CDN) that have what appears to be old webpages and their associated streaming video.  How do I know the content is old?  I inferred it from the date visible on the webpage.

**Edit: The CDN cache is not the same thing as my Firefox cache, so this is not a dupe question.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off the Firefox cache?](http://superuser.com/questions/23134/how-to-turn-off-the-firefox-cache), [How can I always force a reload for some url?](http://superuser.com/questions/482920/how-can-i-always-force-a-reload-for-some-url)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The question refers to all caches, not only those in the client computer's browser.

Comment: That's two questions pointed out there, neither of which are talking about anything but the client browser cache, so I'm not sure why you think it's not a dupe. But hey, takes more than one vote.

Comment: If you re-read my comment, you'll know why it's not a dupe.

Comment: I'm not following -- in your comment what questions is "The question" in your second sentence?  Neither the marked dupes, nor yours (How do I cause Firefox to display only new data; not cached data?) seems to be about anything other than preventing FF's from showing you data form it's cache, and the way to do that is to disable the cache (or hit ctrl-F5 manually each time).  Perhaps edit your question here and add information explaining how this question is different?

Answer (score 0):

Private Browsing mode is your friend (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Or you can Ctrl+F5 to refresh everything.